# After using groupby in Pandas how to find what percentage of a column is negative

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a df something like this with two columns: name and score. Example

```
name     score
John       0.5
George     0.2
John      -0.94
Paul      -0.2
Mary       0.44
Paul      -0.6
Mary      -0.89
```

I want to groupby name and get the what percentage of their scores are negative, so should look like

```
name      negative_score_percent
John      50%
George    0%
Paul      100%
Mary      50%
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby('name')(['score'] < 0).sum()
```

after which I would just divide it by the total number of scores like this:

```
no_of_scores = df.groupby('name')['scores'].count()
```

and then merge the two and divide but I get an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

and I'm not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that using `lambda`:

```
result = df.groupby('name')['score'].apply(lambda x: (x < 0).mean() * 100).reset_index(name='negative_score_percent')

print(result)
```

In the example above `mean()` might be not that obvious, but it is just a short version of `sum(x) / len (x)` which, in this case, gives number of values below 0 divided by total number of values.

Answer (score 1):

First identify the negative values, then `groupby`:

```
out = (df['score'].lt(0)
 .groupby(df['name'], sort=False)
 .agg(negative_score_percent='mean')
 .mul(100).reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
     name  negative_score_percent
0    John                    50.0
1  George                     0.0
2    Paul                   100.0
3    Mary                    50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you mispelled syntax

> `df.groupby('name')(['score'] < 0).sum()`

and in second brackets you simply compare list ['score'] with int 0.

Solution you're looking for can be written somehow like this:

```
df_neg = (df
            [df.score < 0]
            .groupby('name')
            .count()
            .rename(columns={'score': 'neg_score'}))
df_all = (df
            .groupby('name')
            .count()
            .rename(columns={'score': 'all_score'}))

(pd
    .merge(
        df_neg,
        df_all,
        on='name',
        how='right'
        )
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .assign(
        negative_score_percent=lambda df_: (df_.neg_score / df_.all_score) * 100
        )
    .drop(
        ['neg_score', 'all_score'],
        axis=1
        )
    )
```